# Recover data after reformatting an ext4 partition and after trying recovery tools

Tags: linux, ext4

I have mistakenly formatted a linux ext4 partition in the hard disk and wanted to recover the data. I have ran testdisk and fsck.ext4 on the /dev/sdb1 partition, but with no luck. Testdisk has recovered data with different file names and folder structures.

I couldn't get a proper filesystem structure. I am planning to recover data once again by trying gparted and ddrescue. Will it still help in recovering the data since I have already tried correcting and recovering with the testdisk and fsck.ext4 utility?

Would greatly recommend your suggestions to get back my lost data during a format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover/undelete files from an ext4 partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/170857/how-can-i-recover-undelete-files-from-an-ext4-partition) or https://superuser.com/questions/822379/accidentally-formatted-ext4-partition?

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I couldnt recover the files in a proper filestructure using photorec and my question is whether it can still be retrieved using gparted or ddrescue tools ?. SInce the testdisk and fsck has performed correction on the filesystem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal hard drive is dying. Is this the right procedure to recover data (with ddrescue)?](https://superuser.com/questions/792634/internal-hard-drive-is-dying-is-this-the-right-procedure-to-recover-data-with)

Comment: `ddrescue` just copies raw data. It's useful with a failing disk because it tries hard to get as much data as it can, despite hardware errors. If the disk (hardware) is healthy, it doesn't matter if you work with it or with a copy created with `ddrescue`. If other tools *alter* data in place, you may want to work with a copy (to be able to start over if anything goes wrong). `ddrescue` can give you a copy but this is all it does.

Comment: Is the disk an SSD, or a magnetic HDD?

Comment: Its a magnetic HDD